# How to deploy Artifactory on K8s using helm charts

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, artifactory

I'm trying to deploy artifactory using helm charts on my minikube K8s cluster to explore it. I signed up for free 30days trial and run following commands to start it:
*helm repo add jfrog https://charts.jfrog.io/

helm install -name artifactory jfrog/artifactory*
unfortunately it never comes up. When I checked there is problem with postgres password.
I'm not able to login to postgreSQL using credentials from the secret (tried with artifactory and postgres user).
It works with OpenSource version, when I run:
*helm install -name artifactory jfrog/artifactory-oss*
it works without problems.
Please try to help with that.

regards,
Piotr

Comment: I suspect your initial install was not on a clean env and the install generated a new PostgreSQL password. Try removing any exiting PVC first. Also, set the PostgreSQL password with your install command: `--set postgresql.postgresqlPassword=password123` and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem, the cause was, my first installation try failed and that lefts a PVC that contains 'auto-generated' password and next installation try the password is not the same...

Either delete PVC, for me, it is called 'artifactory-volume-artifactory-0'
Or if it is your first installation and you don't use 'auto-generate', '--set postgresql.postgresqlPassword=password123', should do it....